# Any way to extend org-mode tags to include characters like "-"?

Tags: emacs, tags, org-mode

BRIEF:  can the characters permitted in org-mode tags be extenced in any way?

E.g. to include -, dashes?

DETAIL:

I see

> http://orgmode.org/org.html#Tags
>
> Tags are normal words containing letters, numbers, ‘_’, and ‘@’. Tags
>   must be preceded and followed by a single colon, e.g., ‘:work:’.

I am somewhat surprised that this is not extensible.  Is it, and I have missed it?

TODO keywords can include dashes.  Occasionally I would like to treat TODOs as intermiscible wth tags - e.g.  move a TODO to a tag, and vice versa - but this syntax difference gets in the way.

Before I start coding, does anyone know why dashes are not allowed?   I conjecture confusion with timestamps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not certain, but it is likely because certain agenda search strings use "-" as an operator, and there is not yet a way to escape those using "-".

I have used hyphens for properties and spaces for todo kw with no problems for my purposes, but I have not tried them in searches.

The new exporter will be included in 8.0 and with it a detailed description of syntax.  If you want to file a feature request to allow hyphens, perhaps by allowing escaping in search strings, now is the time to do it.

Comment: This is pretty much my experience, e.g. for the character "-":  (1) - in tags not accepted; (2) - in todo keywords accepted, recognized, colored, etc; (3) but many searches, particularly tags searches that treat todo keywords like properties, do not work; (4) various attempts at escaping, backslashing, quouting " or ', etc., do not work.